# Rails 6 has_many build relation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On board `Rails 6.0.2.1` and `ruby 2.6.2`

models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :notes
end

class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

user = User.new
note = user.notes.build
note.user #=> nil - WHY???? SHOULD BE User
user.notes #=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Note id: nil, ...>]
```

Seems like I missed something in rails settings... could anybody help me, please???

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

Checked on another project with Rails 5, works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my co-worker. Resolved `inverse_of` helped.

has_many :notes, inverse_of: :user